# Unable to share sockets among threads perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, sockets, threadpool

I am building a multithreaded perl TCP server that uses different threads to handle different clients. For this purpose, I am maintaining a thread pool which keeps track of whether the thread is idle or working.
In the main thread, I open a listening socket and bind to a specific port using:

```
$socket = new IO::Socket::INET(Localhost => '127.0.0.1', 
     LocalPort => '5000', 
     Proto => 'tcp', 
     Listen => $MAX_THREADS, Reuse => 1) or die "Error in Socket Creation:  $!\n";
```

The main thread also listens to any incoming connections using socket->accept() and if successful passes this return socket to the child thread which handles it and sends an acknowledgement to the client corresponding to the socket. However, I was unable to pass this socket.

I googled a bit and having no luck, later I decided to maintain a global hashmap of incoming sockets which can be later accessed by the child threads(the hashmap is shared) and then work on it.

However perl is giving me an error as to Invalid value for shared scalar. Here is the code bit:

```
$sochandler->{$tid} = $socket->accept(); 
#$sochandler is the shared global hashmap with keys as thread IDs
```

PS: I am newbie to perl and I have tried to explain as much as I can regarding my problem

Here is the subroutine code which is run by every child thread:

```
sub worker
{
    my ($work_q) = @_;
    my $tid = threads->tid();
    do {
    printf("Idle     -> %2d\n", $tid);
    $IDLE_QUEUE->enqueue($tid);
    my $work_tid = $work_q->dequeue();
    my $work = $sochandler->{$work_tid};
        last if ($work_tid < 0);
    printf("            %2d <- Working\n", $tid);
    while (($work_tid > 0) && ! $TERM) {
    print "Accepted New Client Connection From: $work->peerhost(), $work->peerport()\n";
    my $data = "ACK from server";
        $work->send($data);
    $work->recv($data,1024);
    print "Received from Client : $data\n"; 
    }
} while (! $TERM);
    printf("Finished -> %2d\n", $tid);
}
```

Comment: What platform are you running this script on? (Windows, Linux, other?)

Comment: Linux is my platform @duskwuff

Comment: You can share fileno() of socket. I'll suggest do not use threads for your task. Try AnyEvent or Coro, this will eliminate sharing problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because the $tid is not declared as a shared variable.  You need to share 'deep' so that not only is the hash shared, but also its keys.